# Firebase process child snap that has dictionary inside it in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm trying to get back information from some users in Firebase.
To do that, I'm running a query that selects the users based on the user's id I passed.
The problem is that, inside the user object, there is another `object` and 
when I try to get the entire user in my code, I only get that last object.

This is what a user looks like in Firebase:

```
USERIDHERE
{
  "coins" : 4850,
  "name" : "Jogador 1020",
  "score" : 22,
  "unlocked" : {
    "000" : true,
    "KA0293" : true
  }
}
```

This is the code to get the user

```
ref.child("users").child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                            if let dict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                                print(dict) 
                            }

                        }

                    })
```

When I print the dict, instead of getting all the user information, I only get in this example the following output:

```
["000": 1, "KA0293": 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Database:

[image]

---

## Code:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let refUsers = ref.child("users")
let refUser = refUsers.child("123")

refUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
  if snap.exists() {
    if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
      print(dict)
    }
  }
}
```

---

## Print's output:

```
["unlocked": {
    000 = 1;
    KA0293 = 1;
}, "name": Jogador 1020, "score": 22, "coins": 4850]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ref.child("users").child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

// you can get your user's name like below:

username = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as! String

  if let dict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {
                                    print(dict) 
                                }
                        })
```

Snapshot already has user's all information.